# Canceling textboxes if I type in other textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I got few textboxes in my form. I would like to type in one textbox and the other textboxes will be automatically canceled (Canceled so the user wont be able to type anymore in the other textboxes).
If the user delete the word he typed in the textbox (or in other words: if the textbox is empty) all other textboxes will be enabled again.

Here is what I got so far:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            // Disable other textboxes (I have no idea how can I do that).
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            // Enable other textboxes
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            // Keep this comboBox enabled while typing in textBox1.
        }
    }
```

How can I disable other textboxes while typing in priticillar textbox? (also keeping comboBox enabled).

DO NOTICE: I would like to do the same on textBox2 (when I type in textBox2, textbox 1 and 3 will be disabled) and textBox3.

Comment: BTW this sounds completely utterly awful UX. Please don't do this.

Comment: You also do not note what UI tech you are using. If you are using WPF, you would do this differently from if you used WinForm and if you were doing this in WebForm or MVC you would in fact achieve this using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a condition on your 'else if', just 'else' will do, as if the length is more than 0, the only other possibility is 0.  Also you can use the sender instead of hardcoding the control name.

Then set the Enabled property for the textbox's you want disabled. You can loop through all the textbox's on the form, excluding the one you are typing into, or just manually list them.  SImpler is putting the textbox's in a groupbox, then if you disable the groupbox it will disable the controls with in it.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var senderTextBox    = (TextBox)sender;
    var textBoxesEnabled = senderTextBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0;

    textBox2.Enabled = textBoxesEnabled;
    textBox3.Enabled = textBoxesEnabled;

    // OR

    groupBox1.Enabled = textBoxesEnabled;
}
```

REPLY EDIT: You can chain of textbox's, say 4 of them, disable the last 3, then:

```
void TextBox1TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var isTextEmpty  = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Trim() == "";
    textBox2.Enabled = !isTextEmpty;
}
void TextBox2TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var isTextEmpty  = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Trim() == "";
    textBox1.Enabled = isTextEmpty;
    textBox3.Enabled = !isTextEmpty;
}
void TextBox3TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var isTextEmpty  = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Trim() == "";
    textBox2.Enabled = isTextEmpty;
    textBox4.Enabled = !isTextEmpty;
}
void TextBox4TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var isTextEmpty  = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Trim() == "";
    textBox3.Enabled = isTextEmpty;
}
```

But for a large amount of textbox's, another alternative is having multiple textbox share the same TextChanged event. You need to click on each TextBox control, go into the Events list and manually select the method for TextChanged. Here is the method:

```
private void TextBoxGroup_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var groupOrder    = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };
    var senderTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    var senderIndex   = groupOrder.IndexOf(senderTextBox);

    var isTextEmpty = senderTextBox.Text.Trim() == "";
    if (senderIndex != 0) groupOrder[senderIndex - 1].Enabled = isTextEmpty;
    if (senderIndex != groupOrder.Count - 1) groupOrder[senderIndex + 1].Enabled = !isTextEmpty;
}
```

Comment: It works, but lets assume I want to use textbox2 and disable 1 and 3, I need for that if statement.. how can I fit your code into if statement?

Comment: Updated my answer which may help.

Comment: Updated again, looked back at my answer and realised a List of TextBox controls could be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Controls` collection and some `LINQ`:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{ 
     var textboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.Name != "textBox1");
     foreach(var tBox in textboxes)
         tBox.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Though you forgot to add tBox.Enabled = true; code on the empty if statement.

Comment: I used else if to make the same thing on textBox2 (and textBox1 and 3 will be disabled) and it didn't worked, why?

Comment: because of the condition `x.Name != "textBox1"`

Comment: So how can I fix that?